# Converting large web applications from mysql_connect to PDO usage

Tags: mysql, pdo, server, mysql-connect

I got an assignment to create a new server environment. My boss decided to switch to a new version of PHP, what I encouraged. I just installed PhpMyAdmin on the new server and got a warning that the mqsql_connect function is deprecated. I understand this an old method and we should start using PDO but we have so many query's which should be changed too when we step over to PDO right? It will take a very long time too change all these query's and it will take even longer to test them all.. Is there a way to make this easier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it easier at this point would be to create a PDOproxy class that remaps/mimick mysql_xxx calls. Then you can do a search replace over your project providing your "proxy" is "perfect".

Comment: I'm afraid this will only work with the connection methods. But because of the way PDO handles update/insert/delete etc. query's will prevent us from using this method..